# Continuous image capturing using phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is there any way to capture an images on every second on camera. I am using phonegap Camera API to capture an image and its working fine. No i need to capture an image on every second without pressing capture button. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: I found ARviewer-phoneGap (Augmented Reality)
You could edit the code to see how they implement camera and graphic data area.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a *NSTimer* :

```
myTimerShoot = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(mySnapshotMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```